# Data Factory trigger on Blob in different resource group is failing

Tags: permissions, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-group

I have a requirement where I have a Data Factory in one resource group and a blob storage in another storage group. I need to create a trigger on Data factory pipeline when a blob created in blob storage. I am getting this error while my pipeline is invoked.

```
The Microsoft.EventGrid resource provider is not registered in subscription ***** . Register the provider in the subscription and retry the operation. 
Activity id:6566a4c8-0a1c-4a9e-8940-ce62e43264e3, timestamp: 6/26/2020 8:02:56 AM (UTC)
```

As I understood from error, its permission issue but I am not sure how I can enable this connectivity. Can anyone help.

Comment: Do you use ADF portal or use ARM?

Comment: Hi @BowmanZhu  I use ADF portal.

Comment: I have post an answer, please have a try.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So from the error, I think you should follow these steps:

Go to azure portal, and go to your subscription:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Search `Microsoft.EventGrid` in resource provider and then register `Microsoft.EventGrid`.

Let me know whether you can solve this problem.:)

Comment: Thank You for this answer @Bowman Zhu . This was pretty simple but saved me :)